# Connecting a chat channel made by socket.io

Tags: socket.io

I am trying to making a chat bot for a page using socket.io. I connected to their main chat with this code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>ChatBot</title>
</head>
<body>

  <script src="https://chat.clansy.tv:3030/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
  <script>
    var socket = io('https://chat.clansy.tv:3030');
    socket.on('connect', function(){
      document.body.innerHTML = 'Connected!!';
    });
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Now i am trying to connect https://clansy.tv/chat/kodbilenbot this chat box with my username. Thanks for help ^^

Comment: Did u find any solution on how to create a chatbot in Socket.io ?? Please tell me as well. I am in the similar problem